# Applying relative values to an array

Tags: java

I need to assign a value to the first element a 2D array and then use a for loop to assign a relative value to the other elements.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
  int[][] a = new int[6][5];

  a[0][0] = 3; 

  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
  {
    for (int j = 1; i < 5; i++) 
    {
      a[i][j] = a[i][j-1] + 3;
      System.out.println(a[i][j]); 
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the initial value into the first `for` loop, and assign to the first index of the outside array. Something like,

```
// a[0][0] = 3; 

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    a[i][0] = (i == 0) ? 3 : a[i - 1][a[i - 1].length - 1];
```

Otherwise, `a[i][j-1]` is the default (`0`) when `i` is greater than `0`.

Comment: I don't want to set a fixed value of 0 in a[i][0] because I want all elements of the array to have a value relative to the previous one. And I want the values to be relative, so why is the value always 3?

Comment: @Mr.Spencer Edited. You'll need to access the previous array's last value when `i` isn't `0`.

Comment: It produces this result: 6 3 3 3 3